# ggplot add polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon

I would like to plot a polygon around my significant 'cluster' such as in this example [image: Sample image].

Here is some sample data:

```
freq <- rep(seq(1:3),9)
variable <- c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T6", "T6", "T6", "T7", "T7", "T7", "T8", "T8", "T8", "T9", "T9", "T9")
value <- c(20.6130,  62.1860,  47.3200 , 23.3160 ,127.4400, 144.1300 , 22.5650, 177.0500, 218.4700,  17.4520, 180.1600, 200.0300 ,  8.1023, 144.9400 ,141.0000 , -4.9658 ,
       100.4500 , 96.1530, -4.9658, 64.3770 , 69.3220 , -4.9658 , 37.6850,  45.2310 , -4.9658,  17.8370,  21.9650)
sign <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

df <- data.frame(freq, variable, value, sign)
```

If a combination between time (i.e., T1-T9) and Frequency (1-3 Hz) is significant is denoted by `df$sign == 1`.

The following code generates the plot.

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = freq, fill = value)) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.6, hjust = 1))+
  geom_raster() +
  scale_y_continuous("Frequency [Hz]", limits = c(), breaks = c(unique(df$freq)), labels = as.character(c(unique(df$freq))))+
  scale_x_discrete("Time", labels = c("0-100", "100-200", "200-300", "300-400", "400-500", "500-600", "600-700", "700-800", "800-900"))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(name= "Activity [%]", colors = viridis_pal(direction = -1)(20), limits=c(-20, 250))
```

I appreciate any hints on how to best do this in ggplot.

Comment: Your data does not include the data2 dataframe that you reference in  scale_y_continuous(). Have you explore the ggforce package for the shape? https://www.data-imaginist.com/2019/the-ggforce-awakens-again/

Comment: Ah v sorry, I corrected that. Will check the ggforce package! I have found several examples, but not for a discrete x axis.